# Glob pattern expression for a hexadecimal number in TCL?

Tags: regex, tcl, glob

I am trying understand the difference between glob and regex patterns. I need to do some pattern matching in TCL.

The purpose is to find out if a hexadecimal value has been entered.

1. The value may or may not start with 0x
2. The value shall contain between 1 and 12 hex characters i.e 0-9, a-f, A-F and these shall follow the 0x if it exists

The thing is that glob does not allow use of {a,b} to tell about how many characters to look for. Also, at start I tried to use (0x[Xx])? but I think this is not working.

It is not essential to use glob. I can see that there are subtle differences between glob and regex. I just want to know if this can be done only through regex and not glob.

Comment: What do you mean by "glob matching" exactly? Why don't you show actual Tcl code that you tried?

Comment: I used "string match" in Tcl which is different from regexp in Tcl

Comment: `string match` alone won't be sufficient, but you can build a script on top of it that outperforms `regexp` for your case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tcl's glob patterns are *much* simpler than regular expressions. All they support is:

1. `*` to mean any number of any character.
2. `?` to mean any single character.
3. `[…]` to mean any single character from the set (the chars inside the brackets, which may include ranges).
4. `\x` to mean mean a literal `x` (which can be any character). That's how you put a glob metacharacter in a glob pattern.

They're also always anchored at both ends. (Regular expressions are much more powerful. They're also slower. You pay for power.)

To match hex numbers like `0xF00d`, you'd use a glob pattern like this:

```
0x[0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F]
```

(or, as an actual Tcl command; we put the pattern in `{`braces`}` to avoid needing lots of backslashes for all the brackets…)

```
string match {0x[0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F]} $value
```

Note that we have to match an exact number of characters. (You can shorten the pattern by using case-insensitive matching, to `0x[0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f]`.)

Matching hex numbers is better done with `regexp` or `scan` (which also parses the hex number). Everyone likes to forget `scan` for parsing, yet it's quite good at it…

```
regexp {^0x([[:xdigit:]]+)$} $value -> theHexDigits
```

```
scan $value "0x%x" theParsedValue
```

Comment: The scan command is a new thing I have not used yet, lets see

Comment: @Donal: "Note that we have to match an exact number of characters" ... this can be lifted by computing the match pattern, see my updated post.

Comment: @Donal: "Everyone likes to forget scan for parsing", I agree, but how would one encode {1,12} using `scan`?

Comment: ... I meant to write: "... `scan` alone."

Comment: @Donal, I am looking for a program that can be used to debug TCL code. This means do things like step through code, view trace of function calls, watch variables type and value, add breakpoints, look at variable type by hovering over e.t.c. Could you kindly recommend something that you are familiar with. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

> The thing is that glob does not allow use of {a,b} to tell about how
> many characters to look for. Also, at start I tried to use (0x[Xx])?
> but I think this is not working.

A commonly used regular expression, not specific to Tcl at all, is `^(0[xX])?[A-Fa-f0-9]{1,12}$`.

### Update

As Donal writes, there is a power-cost tradeoff when it comes to `regexp`. I was curious and, for the given requirements (optional `0x` prefix, range check `[1,12]`), found that a carefully crafted script using `string` operations incl. `string match` (see `isHex1` below) outperforms `regexp` in this setting (see `isHex2`), whatever the input case:

```
proc isHex1 {str min max} {
    set idx [string last "0x" $str]
    if {$idx > 0} {
      return 0
    } elseif {$idx == 0} {
      set str [string range $str 2 end]
    }
    set l [string length $str]
    expr {$l >= $min && $l <= $max && [string match -nocase [string repeat {[0-9a-f]} $l] $str]}
}

proc isHex2 {str min max} {
    set regex [format {^(0x)?[[:xdigit:]]{%d,%d}$} $min $max]
    regexp $regex $str
}
```

`isHex1` extends the idea of computing the `string match` pattern based on the input length (w/ or w/o prefix) and `string repeat`. My own timings suggest that `isHex1` runs at least 40% faster than `isHex2` (all using `time`, 10000 iterations), in a worst case (within range, final character decides). Other cases (e.g., out-of-range) are substantially faster.

Comment: Nobody else accounted for the optional leading `0x`. Good catch.

Answer (score 2):

The glob syntax is described in the [`string match`](http://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/string.htm#M35) documentation. Compared to regular expressions, glob is a blunt instrument.

With [regular expressions](http://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/re_syntax.htm), you get the standard character classes, including `[:xdigit:]` to match a hexadecimal digit.

To contrast with mrcalvin's answer, a Tcl-specific regex would be: `(?i)^0x[[:xdigit:]]{1,12}$`

- the leading `(?i)` means the expression will be matched case-insensitively.

If all you care about is determining if the input is a valid *number*, you can use `string is integer`:

```
set s 0xdeadbeef
string is integer $s  ;# => 1

set s deadbeef
string is integer $s  ;# => 0

set s 0xdeadbeetle
string is integer $s  ;# => 0
```

Comment: To avoid surprises with empty strings, use `string is integer -strict $s`.

Comment: @gless, I am looking for a program that can be used to debug TCL code. This means do things like step through code, view trace of function calls, watch variables type and value, add breakpoints, look at variable type by hovering over e.t.c. Could you kindly recommend something that you are familiar with. Thanks.

Comment: The \@Tclers twitter feed recently posted about https://github.com/puremourning/TclProDebug. I haven't used it myself. The ActiveState Komodo IDE can debug Tcl: https://www.activestate.com/products/komodo-ide/